# Use variables in text fields of TFS release definition form

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to use variables like `$(Release.ReleaseName)` in the multiline edit fields of the release definition edit form in TFS 2017 like shown here? It seems not to be working as expected.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue; it works fine. What update of TFS 2017 are you on?

Comment: @DanielMann: Where can I see the version of my TFS from the web interface?

Comment: My version is 15.112.26301.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the ***TFS2017 Update1 RTM***, got the same result as you. It seems not support on this version.

Suggest you to update your TFS2017 to latest version  ***Update3 RC***, it works fine. The variable expand as expected.

[image]

Comment: Haven't tried with TFS2017 update2 RTM version, guess it should also worked. There are many  regenerations on update2 version.